# How to show font in "7 Segment" Style - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, fonts, windows-phone-8.1, seven-segment-display

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8.1 and was thinking that is it possible to use a custom FontFamily to display the text/numbers in 7-Segment Style ? I looked for those fonts in the present FontFamily but found none.

Can I use fonts from other resources to use in WP App.
If Yes, then how ?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5887fa8e-ca3a-4296-80d7-1e0188ae1598/how-to-make-7-segment-display-in-my-app-?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

You can create the font in ttf format and include it in your project. Use the font in textblocks by setting the fontfamily of the textblock.

Comment: But I don't know how can I do this. Means how to create fonts in TTF and add them in my project